# how to sum element in array base key

Tags: php, array-sum

i have array like this

```
[1001] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500
        )

    [1204] => Array
        (
            [0] => 750
        )

    [1202] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 10000
            [2] => 138456
        )

    [1203] => Array
        (
            [0] => 300
        )



)
```

i want Sum each element of array in key to new output like this

```
[1001] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500
        )
[1204] => Array
        (
            [0] => 750
        )
[1202] => Array
        (
            [0] => 148456

        )
[1203] => Array
        (
            [0] => 300
        )





)
```

Thanks !

Comment: We do not provide free coding services here. Please provide your code and we will happy to help you debug it if you are at a loss.

Comment: The PHP documentation may help you get started: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Comment: Thanks The problem Solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to apply [`array_sum`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to each of the elements of the array:

```
$sum_array = array_map(function ($v) { return array_sum($v); }, $array);
print_r($sum_array);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/I2oAd)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. Good luck!

```
    $data=[
        1001 => [ 500],1024 => [750],1202 =>[0,10000,138456],1203=>[300]
    ];


    foreach($data as $key => $value){

            if(count($data[$key]) > 1){
                    $data[$key]=array_sum($data[$key]);
            }else{
                $data[$key] =$data[$key];
            }

    }
```